# making html5 video to fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a custome HTML5 Video player, where in the HTML Page there is a video tag and another DIV tag where i have put the controls. The Control DIV has play button,Pause button, Fullscreen button etc. Now i am trying to make the video full screen on the click of the full screen button. I have written the code making the use of requestFullscreen(). This code is not throwing any error but its neither working. Could someone please tell me where i am going wrong??

```
var controls = {
video: $("#player"),  //this is the video element
fullscreen: $("#fullscreen")  //This is the fullscreen button.
};

controls.fullscreen.click(function(){
var elem = controls.fullscreen;
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    controls.video.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    controls.video.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    controls.video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`controls.fullscreen` and `controls.video` are both jQuery objects, not DOM elements. You want the elements inside the jQuery objects, which you can get with [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
var controls = {
    video: $("#player").get(0),  //this is the video element
    fullscreen: $("#fullscreen").get(0)  //This is the fullscreen button.
};
```

jQuery objects don't have a `requestFullscreen` property, so none of your `if` statement were running (and if they had run, `video.requestFullscreen` wold have failed).

Comment: Sweet!!! Thanks a lot...i think i had kept my brain under a rock while coding... thank you very much..:-)