# HTML5 Video Fullscreen onclick

Tags: jquery, html

Can anyone help on this. I was advised to set up my file like below to have a click on an image trigger an HTML5 fullscreen video that is not shown but I get a function error. Do I need to include some library? It seems to not reconginize the command `requestFullscreen`.

```
<body>
   <div class="slide" id="">
       <img src="../root/img/gc_small.png" id="videoPlay" style="margin:200px 0 0 0;">
   </div>

    <video autoplay loop muted controls="false" id="myVideo" style="width:800px;">
        <source src="video/portal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
          $('#videoPlay').on('click', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              $('#myVideo').requestFullscreen();
          });
      });

    </script>
```

Comment: I think [all browsers that currently support `requestFullscreen`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen) require a vendor prefix: `mozRequestFullScreen`, etc. Also I think the capitalization of "`FullScreen`" vs. "`Fullscreen`" may be inconsistent.

Comment: @apsillers I tried `$('#myVideo').webkitRequestFullScreen();` but still get  `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionresidential.html:68 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:3 m.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:3 r.handle`

Comment: Oh, right; the jQuery collection doesn't have a `webkitRequestFullScreen` method. The first element inside the jQuery collection (`$(...)[0]`) has that method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [making html5 video to fullscreen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328870/making-html5-video-to-fullscreen)

Comment: I am still a bit confused on how to get this to work. That link didnt seem to answer the question. It seems this would be a often used script

Comment: Per the link, you need to call `*requestFullscreen` on the DOM element inside the jQuery object. You get the DOM element out using `$(...).get(0)` or bracket access `$(...)[0]`. That's how you get the element; I don't currently understand which part you still need help with, so I'm not sure how to explain it better. Can you explain exactly what you don't understand?

Comment: I got it now. Thanks, it worked just fine

Answer (score 5):

this is something i used recently  for my project

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

      var myVideo =  $("video", _self)[0];
      openFullscreen(myVideo)

    })


function openFullscreen(myVideo) {
  console.log("hitting")
  var elem = myVideo
  console.log(elem)
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice piece of code. It works on my the desktop but it doesn't work in the mobile device. Have you made it work on mobile?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code as i used this code work for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>FullScreen</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style></style>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="onload();">
        <video id="element">
            <source src="video1.mp4"></source>
        </video>
        <a href="#" id="fullscreen">Go Fullscreen</a>
        <script>
            var element = document.getElementById('element');
            var fullscreen = document.getElementById('fullscreen');

            fullscreen.addEventListener('click',function(){
                <!--console.log ('it is working'); -->
                if(element.requestFullscreen){
                    element.requestFullscreen();
                } 
                else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen){
                    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                }
                else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen){
                    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
                }
                else if (element.msRequestFullscreen){
                    element.msRequestFullscreen();
                }   
            });
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```